# AssemblyResolve is trying to get a different version than the one specified in Assembly.Load

Tags: c#, appdomain

I've got a custom assembly-resolving code that is acting up. Initially I'm running a piece of code that attempts to detect all assemblies referenced by a given C# library and this seems to return correct results. Then I'm trying to load those referenced libraries to detect other needed libraries (essentially I'm trying to build a list of ALL libraries that might be needed by a given DLL).

In this particular instance I've got an `Assembly` object reference to `SomeAssembly.dll, version 1` (which appears to be the correct version). However, when running `Assembly.Load` on this reference I enter the `AssemblyResolve` event with `ResolveEventArgs` pointing to `SomeAssembly, version 2`. Attempting to load the "expected" version (i.e. version 1) results in a failure.

a) Why would C# change the version like this?
b) Can I "override" which version I want to load in the `AssemblyResolve` event?

Comment: Can you show your code? Do you have Binding Redirects in the app.config?

Comment: @KlausGütter
Yeah, I feel silly. Had some redirects in my app.config. If you want post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel silly...

I've had some `<bindingRedirect>` in my `App.config`...